# How to add a JQuery function in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I wrote a jQuery function in my EmberJS application but it is not loading.

The jQuery function changes a graph dynamically based on input values.

My code can be viewed using this Developer tool: [Application URL](http://techhysahil.com/Projects/cwd/Ember-app/)

Comment: Application URL ; http://techhysahil.com/Projects/cwd/Ember-app/

Comment: You add it in the didInsertElement hook in the view or component